# Python3 replace tags based on condition of the type of tag

Tags: python, regex

I want all the tags in a text that look like `<Bus:1234|Bob Alice>` or `<Car:5678|Nelson Mandela>` to be replaced with `<a my-inner-type="CR:1234">Bob Alice</a>` and `<a my-inner-type="BS:5678">Nelson Mandela</a>` respectively. So basically, depending on the Type whether `TypeA` or `TypeB`, I want to replace the text accordingly in a text string using Python3 and regex.

I tried doing the following in python but not sure if that's the right approach to go forward:

```
import re
def my_replace():
    re.sub(r'\<(.*?)\>', replace_function, data)
```

With the above, I am trying to do a regex of the`< >` tag and every tag I find, I pass that to a function called `replace_function` to split the text between the tag and determine if it is a `TypeA` or a `TypeB` and compute the stuff and return the replacement tag dynamically. I am not even sure if this is even possible using the `re.sub` but any leads would help. Thank you.

Examples:

- `<Car:1234|Bob Alice>` becomes `<a my-inner-type="CR:1234">Bob Alice</a>`
- `<Bus:5678|Nelson Mandela>` becomes `<a my-inner-type="BS:5678">Nelson Mandela</a>`

Comment: It would be helpful if you could also explain what you want the text to be replaced with. For instance, I want '<a my-inner-type="A:1234">Bob Alice</a>' to become '<a my-inner-type="A:1234">John Smith</a>'

Comment: I'll update my question to make it sound better

Comment: That looks like html... before you get too many more ideas, please read https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3089519 ;)

Comment: @swalladge Thanks. So what do you propose then ?

Comment: It depends on the context... rereading your question it seems that it's simply plain text with various tags as described - if so, you'll probably get away with a regex solution no problems. Hang on, working on an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is perfectly possible with `re.sub`, and you're on the right track with using a replacement function (which is designed to allow dynamic replacements). See below for an example that works with the examples you give - probably have to modify to suit your use case depending on what other data is present in the text (ie. other tags you need to ignore)

```
import re

def replace_function(m):
    # note: to not modify the text (ie if you want to ignore this tag),
    # simply do (return the entire original match):
    # return m.group(0)

    inner = m.group(1)
    t, name = inner.split('|')

    # process type here - the following will only work if types always follow
    # the pattern given in the question
    typename = t[4:]
    # EDIT: based on your edits, you will probably need more processing here
    # eg:
    if t.split(':')[0] == 'Car':
        typename = 'CR'
    # etc

    return '<a my-inner-type="{}">{}</a>'.format(typename, name)

def my_replace(data):
    return re.sub(r'\<(.*?)\>', replace_function, data)



# let's just test it
data = 'I want all the tags in a text that look like <TypeA:1234|Bob Alice> or <TypeB:5678|Nelson Mandela> to be replaced with'
print(my_replace(data))
```

Warning: if this text is actually full html, regex matching will not be reliable - use an html processor like beautifulsoup. ;)

Comment: This looks like something more accurate. Hold on, let me give it a shot and I will post back :)

Comment: This is super close and really awesome, except for the `ID` part. But that's okay, I get the idea and aligns exactly what I already did. I cant take it from here. Thanks for the suggestion. Basically I just didn't know about the `.group` method

Comment: @noobcoder awesome! Glad it was helpful. :) (If it solves your question, please mark the answer as accepted.) Thanks.

Comment: Worked. Accepted

Answer (score 1):

Probably an extension to @swalladge's answer but here we use the advantage of a dictionary, if we know a mapping. (Think replace dictionary with a custom mapping function.

```
import re    

d={'TypeA':'A',
   'TypeB':'B',
   'Car':'CR',
   'Bus':'BS'}

def repl(m):
  return '<a my-inner-type="'+d[m.group(1)]+m.group(2)+'">'+m.group(3)+'</a>'

s='<TypeA:1234|Bob Alice> or <TypeB:5678|Nelson Mandela>'
print(re.sub('<(.*?)(:\d+)\|(.*?)>',repl,s))
print()
s='<Bus:1234|Bob Alice> or <Car:5678|Nelson Mandela>'
print(re.sub('<(.*?)(:\d+)\|(.*?)>',repl,s))
```

---

**OUTPUT**

```
<a my-inner-type="A:1234">Bob Alice</a> or <a my-inner-type="B:5678">Nelson Mandela</a>

<a my-inner-type="BS:1234">Bob Alice</a> or <a my-inner-type="CR:5678">Nelson Mandela</a>
```

Working example [here](https://repl.it/LrX8/0).

---

**regex**
We capture what we need in 3 groups and refer to them through [match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects).Highlighted in bold are the three groups that we captured in the regex.
`<`**`(.*?)`****`(:\d+)`**`\|`**`(.*?)`**`>`
We use these 3 groups in our `repl` function to return the right string.

Comment: This is also good, but @swalladge's aligned better with mine and I already accepted his. But this was a neat solution too. I think I will use the dictionary as well. Thanks

Comment: @noobcoder Request you to not split the match string in the function. `re.sub` returns you the three sections you need neatly! Because you are redoing what `re.sub` had already partly done.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this isn't a complete answer but I'm falling asleep at the computer, but this is the regex that'll match either of the strings you provided, `(<Type)(\w:)(\d+\|)(\w+\s\w+>)`. Check out https://pythex.org/ for testing your regex stuff.

Comment: This is similar to the regex and is good, but I updated my question examples to articulate better, Jason Fry

Answer (score 0):

This code will work if you have it in the form `<Type:num|name>`:

```
def replaceupdate(tag):
    replace = ''
    t = ''
    i = 1
    ident = ''
    name = ''
    typex = ''
    while t != ':':
        typex += tag[i]
        t = tag[i]
        i += 1
    t = ''
    while t != '|':
        if tag[i] == '|':
            break
        ident += tag[i]
        t = tag[i]
        i += 1
    t = ''
    i += 1
    while t != '>':
        name += tag[i]
        t = tag[i]
        i += 1
    replace = '<a my-inner-type="{}{}">{}</a>'.format(typex, ident, name)
    return replace
```

I know it does not use regex and it has to split the text some other way, but this is the main bulk.

Comment: Ahh okay. I see now, well I'll get on to making a set of new code.

Comment: Also you want to have the first and last letter of the type capitalised or what because that is a bit confusing to see as you wanted TypeA -> TypeA but Car -> CR and Bus -> BR.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
import re

def get_tag(match):
    base = '<a my-inner-type="{}">{}</a>'
    inner_type = match.group(1).upper()
    my_inner_type = '{}{}:{}'.format(inner_type[0], inner_type[-1], match.group(2))
    return base.format(my_inner_type, match.group(3))

print(re.sub(r'\<(\w+):(\d+)\W([^\>]+).*', get_tag, '<Bus:1234|Bob Alice>'))

print(re.sub(r'\<(\w+):(\d+)\W([^\>]+).*', get_tag, '<Car:5678|Nelson Mandela>'))
```